# flutter Drawing text when calling flutter code in java

Tags: flutter, dart

I have succeeded in calling a flutter method in Java using 'MethodChannel'.

**Java Code**

```
if(call.method.equals("drawFont")){
   int res = callFlutterMethod(0xF020);
   System.out.println("drawFont Result : " + res);
}

///Call Flutter Method
public static void callFlutterMethod(int nFontData){
   channel.invokeMethod("drawFont", nFontData);
   System.out.println("pass FontData!!");
}
```

**Flutter Code**

```
 onListener(){
    platform.setMethodCallHandler((call) async{
      if(call.method == 'drawFont'){
        print('call java drawFont : ${call.arguments}');
        return Text(String.fromCharCode(call.arguments));
      }
    });
    return Text('Listener Failed');
  }
```

The problem is that whenever I call the flutter method with `methodChannel` in java, I want the widget to be created. If there is a way, please give me a simple example code. Thank you.

**Example**

```
Column(
  children: [
    //call Widget Text
  ],
)
```

Comment: Do you want to add widget to your screen after you invoke `public static void callFlutterMethod(int nFontData)` did I understand you question correct?

Comment: I want to return `return Text(String.fromCharCode(call.arguments));` to the `Column` widget. But the `onListener` method is called back to the MethodChannel. How to return to Widget when called from java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such case you have to use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Your Java code should be looks like

```
@Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor(), YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME).setMethodCallHandler(
      new MethodCallHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
          if (call.method.equals("drawFont")) {
            result.success(0xF020);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Your Flutter code

```
Column(
  children: [
    FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: platform.invokeMethod('drawFont'), 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(String.fromCharCode(snapshot.data));
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error');
          } else {
            return Text('Loading');
          }
        }
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: I am drawing a PDF using `PDF package`. There is no `FutureBuiler` in `pdf.widget`, is there a widget to replace?

Comment: FutureWidget is a standard flutter widget. Or do you have a different question?

Comment: I'm working on drawing a Widget on a PDF. But 'PDFWidget' doesn't have 'FutureBuilder'.